# How to I read several lines in a file faster using python?

Tags: python, file, readlines

As of now I use the following python code:

```
file = open(filePath, "r")
lines=file.readlines()
file.close()
```

Say my file has several lines (10,000 or more), then my program becomes slow if I do this for more than one file. Is there a way to speed this up in Python? Reading various links I understand that readlines stores the lines of file in memory thats why the code gets slow.

I have tried the following code as well and the time gain I got is 17%.

```
lines=[line for line in open(filePath,"r")]
```

Is there any other module in python2.4 (which I might have missed).
Thanks,
Sandhya

Comment: Which links?  I would be interested to see proof that this is the case.

Comment: @Mikel: from the docstring: "readlines([size]) -> list of strings, each a line from the file.  Call readline() repeatedly and return a list of the lines so read. The optional size argument, if given, is an approximate bound on the total number of bytes in the lines returned."

Comment: @DSM: I mean the docs that say `readlines` is slower. ;-)

Comment: @Mike1: ah, that make a _lot_ more sense as a question. :^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for line in file:
```

This gives you an iterator that reads the file object one line at a time and then discards the previous line from memory.

> A file object is its own iterator, for example iter(f) returns f (unless f is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a for loop (for example, for line in f: print line), the next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit. In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining next() with other file methods (like readline()) does not work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer. New in version 2.3.

Short answer: don't assign the lines to a variable, just perform whatever operations you need inside the loop.